# Is it possible to sign and encrypt all outgoing mails with a normal SSL Domain certificate?

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer, smime

I'm sending mails with PHP via a SMTP mail server. I have an SMIME Certificate for one email that sends all those mails (signed and also encrypted sometimes). This works perfectly.

Now I want to buy a (normal not SMIME) SSL Domain certificate (for the whole domain), is it possible to use this for my website and the signing / encrypting of those mails or do I need an SMIME certificate for the mails?

Comment: I don't know if there is a commercial certificate authority that will sign such a certificate but why would you want one? It's generally a bad idea from a security standpoint to use the same key for different purposes.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk how else would you do that? I just want to certify all mails that are coming from that domain. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: When I did this I installed opendkim, generated a key pair and just ran that program on the server as a service and had it stamp all outgoing mail with the private key for a specific domain and you also need to add the public key to the domains records so that others can verify the signature in each email message. Then when you send an email it shows "signed by domain.com" its really difficult to setup initially. You can't use an SSL certificate you have to generate a key pair.

Comment: @mitchelangelo I see, but I don't understand your last sentence. I can't use an SSL certificate, but I have an SSL certificate with a public and private key pair?

Comment: The certs are nearly the same but verification procedures are necessarily different. Certs needs to have appropriate usage fields set for email use, and typical DV certs won’t have that, though they are cryptographically identical. [Let’s encrypt has been asked for this in the past](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/reconsider-s-mime/175504/6), but don’t apparently think it’s worthwhile.

Comment: Opendkim will cryptographically sign each message automatically on your server each time smtp protocol is used for a specified domain name, but to actually encrypt the contents of an email - you would need the recipients public key and some plugin for your mail client which will encrypt your message, Opendkim includes cryptographic signatures in the header and doesn't modify the body of the message. You can read more about setting up and generating keys here: https://wiki.debian.org/opendkim

Answer (score 0):

That won’t work for multiple reasons.

First, while it is technically possible to use an SSL certificate (or rather its private key) to sign or encrypt an email, a mail client won’t do it, because it requires that the certificate has been issued for email usage and for the sender’s email address.

Second, the recipient will have the same problem: their software won’t accept such a signature as valid.

Third, in order to *encrypt* an email, you need the recipient’s public key. Your own certificate doesn’t help you here.

You may want to look into DKIM to sign outgoing emails at the server level, but from your question, it’s not clear to me if that could help you.

Comment: This is mostly true, but many common email clients have S/MIME support built-in as standard, such as Apple mail on both macOS and iOS. Discovery of recipient public keys is generally easy too - you just need someone to send you a signed (but not encrypted) message, and you have all you need.

Comment: @not2savvy Ok I understand. Is there maybe another way to sign all emails of a domain (without DKIM) ?